# jwt refresh tokens without saving anywhere

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, refresh-token

I have implemented refresh tokens in ASP.NET framework like below. It does not require refresh token to be saved anywhere. Can i do the same in ASP.NET Core JWT? The thing I want is not to save the refresh token in the DB or anywhere else.

```
public class RefreshTokenProvider : IAuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        Create(context);
    }

    public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        Receive(context);
    }

    public void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        object inputs;
        context.OwinContext.Environment.TryGetValue("Microsoft.Owin.Form#collection", out inputs);

        var grantType = ((FormCollection)inputs)?.GetValues("grant_type");

        var grant = grantType.FirstOrDefault();

        if (grant == null || grant.Equals("refresh_token")) return;

        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(Constants.RefreshTokenExpiryInDays);

        context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
    }

    public void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);

        if (context.Ticket == null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "invalid token";
            return;
        }

        if (context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc <= DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "unauthorized";
            return;
        }

        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(Constants.RefreshTokenExpiryInDays);
        context.SetTicket(context.Ticket);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

JWT tokens are automatically refreshed when using JWT middleware and they are saved in memory. From my understanding you won't need to write any kind of code. Just set up jwt as a service. If a JWT token is send from the client it will be refreshed on the server side.

JWT tokens info are stored in the memory not in any kind of database. After all you must know what tokens to accept and what to reject as it's impossible not to store anything anywhere. You wont need a seperate token. Simply JWT handles the refresh for you.

Comment: can you please provide me a link or code sample for this.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: it is only sending auth token not refresh token

Comment: Yes because a refresh token is not required as it's automatically refreshes the token. The same thing you do on your Receive function. When the user makes a request with the token the token will be validated and refreshed automatically.